# Image not showing, although data coming successful back from http request (Ionic)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic project and via json I was able to readout my data in the view. But for some reason my image won't come through.

Here is a screenshot of my console:

[image]

As you can see from the picture the data is coming in correctly.

My html code:

```
  <ion-list>
      <div ng-repeat="newsItem in newsItems">
        <a href="#">
            <img ng-src="{{newsItem.picture}}" width="80" height="80">
            <p>{{newsItem.name}}</p>
        </a>        
      </div>
  </ion-list>
```

Anyone has an idea why the image is not showing?

Comment: can you make a plunker ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, first you jsfiddle is broken ! but no biggie, just remove ';' from the first line. Second your json news doesn't have a pictures it's just this ...

`{"newsID":"58","name":"Chemicar     presentation","idk":"new","kind":"news","picture":"58.jpg","picture1":"","start_time":"1446073201"}`

You are binding to `{{newsItem.picture}}` and as you can see your picture it's there as a **58.jpg** but this is not a picture it's just a string of picture name, so that's why it's not showing anything in the html!

Comment: ok thanks, so i guess there is no way to show it with the json?

Comment: it is if your json contain a valid base64 picture

Comment: mmm, ok i will look into it because i dont know if the json is base64 (external json). thanks anyway

Comment: mmm i tried something like this:  <img class="thumbnailNews" ng-src="data:picture/JPEG;base64,{{newsItem.picture}}" width="80" height="80"> but i am getting an error -> net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: and make sure that your `{{newsItem.picture}}` it's something more then a string like '58.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

(Perhaps I should have put this in a comment; totally going to get flamed)

I wonder if it could be a z-index issue?